# Why is my Derived Column Expression Not Giving Me the Results I Expect?

Tags: sql-server, regex, excel, ssis

I am extracting data from an excel sheet and transforming and loading into `Sql Server` `2012`.  I am trying to perform a `Derived Column` transformation on a certain column `'RegistrationNumber'`.

The `'RegistrationNumber'` is in the following formats and not all fixed length:

```
###/####
###/####
###/####
###/####
###/####
###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/####
X###/AB
XYZ##/###
XYZ##/###
ABS###/####
ABCSEDG###FG/####
```

I need to take the `LEFT` of the `'/'` and put in a column on `SQL Server` and I have to take the `RIGHT` of the `'/'` and put it in a different column in `SQL server`:

The following are my expressions in my `derived column` transformation:

```
Derived Column: RegistrationNumber
Derived Column:  Replace 'RegistrationNumber'
Expression: LEFT([RegistationNumber],FINDSTRING([RegistrationNumber],"/",1) - 1)
Data Type: Unicode string [DT_WSTR]
Length:  255

Derived Column: Copy of RegistrationNumber
Derived Column:  Replace 'Copy of RegistrationNumber'
Expression: RIGHT([Copy of RegistrationNumber],FINDSTRING([Copy of   RegistrationNumber],"/",1) - 1)
Data Type: Unicode string [DT_WSTR]
Length:  255
```

For most of the results it did what I wanted.  However some of them I am getting results like the following:

```
/####
##/AA
#/####
A###XY/####
```

The `RIGHT` expression should have results like this:

`####`

NOTE:  The `LEFT`  expression produced all valid results

The following is my `Task` flow:

```
Excel Source
```

to `Copy Column` to `Derived Column` to `Ole DB Command`

Comment: Do any of your records have more than one "/" ????

Comment: Do you think this is a Exel issue?  Excel has been the bane of my existence when using with SSIS.

Comment: Excel and SSIS don't mix well in the slightest. If only they were made by the same company, then I'm sure interoperability would be achieved

Comment: @billinkc Does my `RIGHT` expression look valid?

Comment: One thing I find helpful when working with formulas like you're doing is to create a column in a Derived Task prior to step where you need it. So SlashPosition = `FINDSTRING([RegistrationNumber],"/",1)` Then, your left/right/substring operations are easier to read

Comment: @billinkc thanks for the input.  Does 'Excel' perform better with CozyRoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT is "new" with the 2012 release of SSIS so I'm providing formulas that use substring for people still on 2005/2008

- SlashPosition = FINDSTRING(RegistrationNumber,"/",1)
- LEFT = LEFT(RegistrationNumber,(SlashPosition - 1))
- SUBLEFT = SUBSTRING(RegistrationNumber,1,(SlashPosition - 1))
- RIGHT = RIGHT(RegistrationNumber,LEN(RegistrationNumber) - (SlashPosition))
- SUBRIGHT = SUBSTRING(RegistrationNumber,(SlashPosition + 1),LEN(RegistrationNumber) - SlashPosition)

[image]

At the core of it, your right call is slicing off the last N character but the length your passing is the position where the slash was found. Instead, that position is the length of the string, less the slash position

[image]

As for Excel vs CozyRoc vs anything else. That'll be opinion based but I have found I have the best success when I can get my data in a flat file format (delimited or fixed width). Assuming that's not an option, then I generally prefer to write queries against Excel than use the native table thing.

Comment: I totally agree with the FlatFile strategy. Especially when importing to excel.  If I don't use a FlatFile it will take 30 min.  When I use a FlatFile its almost instantaneous.

Comment: WOW!  that was really helpful.  Am I able to mark this as a "favorite" answer anywhere rather than just an answer?

Comment: The general consensus is that you favorite questions that have outstanding answers. But since you asked the question, you'd always have that on your profile for reference

Answer (score 1):

```
RIGHT([Copy of RegistrationNumber],FINDSTRING([Copy of RegistrationNumber],"/",1) - 1)
```

is not correct to get the string right of the slash character.

For example for `X###/AB` the function RIGHT should copy 2 characters. But FINDSTRING returns 5 which is subtracted by 1 resulting in value 4. Therefore RIGHT returns the last 4 characters from `X###/AB`.

So you need to subtract from length of string the position of the slash character to get the right result.